# Google chrome does not start when running through Twist with Seleniumn

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

Where i work uses Throughworks Twist 2.2 with Selenium for testing automation. For some odd reason on my particular machine  the chrome driver starts but does not load chrome. The console reports no errors and i have no feedback on which to progress with. I installed Twist in the exact same way as everyone else here and it works for them. Twist will run with firefox for me but it is not as reliable as chrome and really impinges on development. The Twist site is typically useless source of information.

I'n not expecting answers but would appreciate any hints as to where i can start looking into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns, out Chrome driver was trying to launch a Chrome version installed under another user account, that was probably out of date. Delete old user profile and it works.

It would be good to find out where Chrome Driver gets this config from.